# How to collapse object (in frame one) from other frame (frame two) WUA

Tags: c#, xaml, frame

> I have simple problem (hoping so). I need to collapse (or do some
> other changes) to object in form/frame from other form/frame (child or
> parent) but I don't know how to do it. It's good to mention that I'm
> developing Windows Universal Apps. And also I need to load frame from
> other frame to some other frame...
>
> I like to make it very simple and easy to you to understand and that's
> why I like to show really simple example what I mean.
>
> Sorry my English , not my mother language.
>
> THE PAGE ONE XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Content="LoadFrame" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="KillMeOne" Content="Kill Me From Frame Two"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="TheSecondFrame" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Frame x:Name="FrameThreeComesHere" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

> THE PAGE TWO XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Load Frame Three From Here Form In 'FrameThreeComesHere-frame' But How?"/>
        <Button Content="Kill The Button From Page One But How?"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

> THE PAGE THREE XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="HelloWord!"/>
</Grid>
```

> THE PAGE ONE CS CODE...

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TheSecondFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageTwo));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a data context for Page 1, Bind the Visibility of the Element you want to hide to a property of the data context. Then from Page 2, get the data context of Page 1, change the property to change the Visibility of the element on Page 1.

Comment: Oh please, can U send me a small example. I just don't get it. Thanks!